# Generate Downloadable PDF's from HTML Tables

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, html-table

Can you suggest me some tools to generate downloadable PDFs from HTML tables?

If possible, compatible with Twitter Bootstrap.

Ps.: I've tried Prawn, but I'd like to know some other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you need to know**

Basic Perl scripting, HTML, Perl module installation

**Introduction**

The Adobe © PDF files is one of the popular file format for transferring documents. One of the reasons for this is that it displays the document the way it will be printed (WYSIWYG). Since it does not require a word processor to browse the document, it is also a lot more convenient. You just need their reader to be able to browse the document.

Perl has a module that will allow you to convert HTML files to PDF documents. This is done by using the HTML::HTMLDoc module.

**Installation**

You need to download the HTMLDoc product from Easy Software Products. Install it first then you can proceed to download the HTML::HTMLDoc module from CPAN. Once you download it, install it as you would typical Perl modules.

**Generating your PDF Document**

First thing to do is to use the module and create your instance of the HTML::HTMLDoc package.

You can then pass a full HTML document to the package or tell it to generate the PDF document from an HTML file.

**Sample code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::HTMLDoc;
use strict;
####################################################
# This script is distributed according to the terms of
# the Perl Artistic License. Use at your own risk
# © 2004 Philip L. Yuson
####################################################
my $str = '
<html>
<body>
<p><font size=14pt><b>HTML to PDF Document</b></font></p>
<p>Let us see how this will work</p>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>This is a row in a table</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is another row</td></tr>
</table>
<HR>
copyright © 2004 Philip L. Yuson 
</body>
</html>';
my $html = new HTML::HTMLDoc(); # Start instance
$html->set_page_size('letter'); # set page size
$html->set_bodyfont('Arial'); # set font
$html->set_left_margin(1, 'in'); # set margin
$html->set_html_content($str); # contents to convert
my $pdf = $html->generate_pdf(); # generate document
$pdf->to_file('article.pdf'); # save document
```

Save this as pdf.pl and run it by starting a command line and typing this:

**perl pdf.pl**

**This should generate a PDF file similar to this.**

Generating PDF files for download on the web

to generate a PDF which can be downloaded, without saving it to a file, you can use the same script as above except that you need to change the last line. However, to make our example more interesting, we will put the date and time on the document also. So the script will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::HTMLDoc;
use Date::Calc;
use strict;
####################################################
# This script is distributed according to the terms of
# the Perl Artistic License. Use at your own risk
# © 2004 Philip L. Yuson
####################################################
my @c = Date::Calc::Today_and_Now();
my $str_temp;
foreach (@c) {
 $str_temp .= sprintf("%02d:", $_);
}
my $str = "
<html>
<body>
<p><font size=14pt><b>HTML to PDF Document</b></font></p>
<p>Let us see how this will work</p>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>This is a row in a table</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is another row</td></tr>
</table>
<HR>
This document was generated:
$str_temp
copyright © 2004 Philip L. Yuson 
</body>
</html>";
my $html = new HTML::HTMLDoc(); # Start instance
$html->set_page_size('letter'); # set page size
$html->set_bodyfont('Arial'); # set font
$html->set_left_margin(1, 'in'); # set margin
$html->set_html_content($str); # contents to convert
my $pdf = $html->generate_pdf(); # generate document
# Tell browser this is a a PDF document
print "Content-Type: Application/pdf\n\n"; 
$pdf->to_string(); # Send the document
```